# Summation with factorial powers and binonial numbers

Tags: combinatorics, summation, factorial

I would like to find a closed form expression for the sum
\begin{equation*}
S(n,N)\triangleq \sum_{c=0}^n N^{[c]}\,\binom{n}{c} \qquad n\leq N
\end{equation*}
where, clearly, $N,n$ are integers and $N^{[c]}$ is the (falling) factorial power, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
N^{[c]}\triangleq \frac{N!}{(N-c)!}
\end{equation*}
I was thinking to study the problem by induction on $n$ (or maybe on $N$), but I don't know if it is the right way to obtain the solution. Since I'm a little bit confused, any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Seems like an exponential generating function might help.

Comment: It is the coefficient  of $x^n/n!$ in $f(x)=(1+x)^Ne^x,$ but not sure if that will have a closed form. You will certainly get a recursion - for $n=0$ you get $1,$ and for $N>0$  I think you get $$s(n,N)=N\cdot S(n-1,N-1)+S(n-1,N).$$

Answer (score 1):

If I do not misread it, making the problem more general
$$S(n,N,x)= \sum_{c=0}^n \frac{N!}{(N-c)!}\,\binom{n}{c}\,x^c$$
$$S(n,N,x)=(-1)^n\,x^n\,U\left(-n,N-n+1,-\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ where appears Tricomi's confluent hypergeometric function.

Comment: Is it possible to plug $x=1$ to obtain the answer to my initial question?

Comment: @matteogost. Yes, for sure !

Comment: Could you provide more details about the derivation of the result?

Comment: @matteogost. It is the definition of the function.

Comment: can you link me the definition that you are considering?

Comment: @matteogost  https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricU/02/   plus   https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2  plus  https://www.hellenicaworld.com/Science/Mathematics/en/Confluenthypergeometricfunction.html